# How to make smth stand out in for nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to print out like a cinema plan, using user input. User can enter how many lines and seats there are and also the line and the seat number of his own. I know how to make cinema plan, but can't figure out how to put user seat(x) in my for loop.

```
#The code I have
line = 4
seat = 5
myline = 2
myseat = 3

for i in range (1,int(line)+1):
    for j in range (1,int(seat)+1):
        print(j, "", end = ""),
    print()

#Illustration
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 X 4 5
1 2 4 5 5
```

Comment: You want to use an if statement inside your loop. If `i` and `j` match your row and seat number, print an X instead of printing `j`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range (1,int(line)+1):
    for j in range (1,int(seat)+1):
        if i == myline and j == myseat:
            print("X", end = "")
        else:
            print(j, end = "")
    print()
```

This is probably the most straightforward way to solve this.